# How can I design a slotted flap?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, flaps

I have not been able to find satisfactory methods on design of slotted flaps, or flaps in general. Most of the answers are about eyeballing or experience. Can you guide me on what could be good starting points.

The images below are what I have design using internet advice, I would like your comments on it.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Some information about the design considerations, The airfoil is S2091 with a chord of 40cm and a wingspan of 3.2 metres operating between 0.3 to 1.3 million Reynolds number. Its meant for a UAV that weighs around 35kgs. Without flaps the landing speed is around 18 m/s (65kmph) which I want to lower with use of slotted flaps.

So far I am using thumb rules like having flap roughly the shape of an airfoil and their relative position to trailing edge of airfoils as a given percentage of chord length. But hit and trial doesn't feel like an optimal approach to designing and I seek to understand how others approach this problem. I can design the mechanisms and structures myself, I need help with the aerodynamic design.

Comment: Your question is way too broad.  The example looks good to me, voting to close unless you can be more specific about the actual design problem you have encountered.  (I.e. are you asking about aerodynamic shape, structure of the rails, actuation method, etc.?)

Comment: I'm asking what is a good starting point in designing a flap, aerodynamically of course. Stop shooting down questions for no good reason that would actually benefit people.

Comment: Sorry, if the aerodynamics tag was there before I didn’t notice it.  Still, I think it’s a pretty broad question... weight and speed targets seem like a  logical starting point.

Comment: It is a question on aircraft design, which needs to consider all of aerodynamics, structure, actuation etc. Have added the aircraft-design tag and voted to keep open.

Comment: I agree with Michael, this is a very broad question. Answerable, yes, but without no info about what kind of a plane is being designed here, the answer will be very general in nature.

Comment: Abbot & Von Doenhoff, Theory Of Wing Sections. A classic from the 1950s, containing a chapter on design of high lift devices. Chapter 8 contains aerodynamic design information that may be of interest